# How to get id of multiple keyboards connected to one computer with Unix-based system?

Tags: unix, keyboard

I want to program a multiple keyboard / mice application on a Unix machine, probably on a Mac. How can I differentiate keyboard keypress input stream from different keyboards?

Comment: Depends on the windowing system, I suppose, and Apple's window system is different from the standard Unix one (X11).

Comment: There is no general/portable way to do this. I suggest that you choose your platform, upgrade "probably" to "definitely" in your question, and add a tag for the chosen platform to attract people who might know the answer (I know the answer only for Linux, and even then I only know part of it).